# .Net Core 2.1 with a .Net Framework EF6 Repository - The type initializer for 'MethodCallTranslator' threw an exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.1 project which I would like to consume a .Net Framework 4.7 Entity Framework 6 repository. I believe this is possible having followed the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-asp-net-core-project

I have a followed those steps with my project and have created the scoped EF6 context in the Startup.cs file (NetCore21) and I am using DI to access the context in my repository class (NetFx 4.7)

However, when I run my project and perform a query such as:

```
var student = await _context.Students.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

I get this exception thrown about a missing parameter "key". However I am not sure how to work out what this is referring to? I am wondering what would be the best way to debug an exception like this?

> Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'MethodCallTranslator' threw an exception. --->
>   **System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   key**    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key,
>   TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.InitializeMethodTranslators()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator..cctor()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Boolean& found)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

Comment: The link you are following does not have await nor async.  How long before you get the exception.  Want to know if a timeout occurred on the connection or you just got back a response.  I suspect you are not getting back the entire response before processing.

Comment: I have tried it without async/await and get the same exception. Exception is thrown immediately and when I run SQL Profiler I see that no query is executed on the SQL Server.

Comment: As an extra note. The connection string works ok, because if I set it to invalid connection string I correctly get "The underlying provider failed on Open". There seems to be some issue with EF interpreting the query.

Comment: The you are connecting to the wrong server.  Often it is due to using Attach Database (localdb).  LocalDb is an mdf file that is not connected to the SQL Server.  Remove the Attach Database from the connection string.  When a database is attached to a server access through the Server/Instance that is on the login Window of SQL Server Management Studio.   When a mdf file is attached to the server the server owns the file and you cannot connect directly to the file.

Comment: The connection string is correct, the same connection string works fine when used in a standalone .Net Framework project with EF6. It is not using local db, it connects to an actual SQL Server.

Comment: Then is sound like something is wrong with the EDMX mapping file.  Maybe you changed the database and did not refresh the mapping.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue for those who trying to use EDMX based EF6.3+ in .NetCore 3.1. Yes, you're right about the support for EF 6.3+ for .Netcore 3.1 as mentioned in the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-asp-net-core-project

But, like the following blog also mentions the limitation. One of the limitations is that you cannot use EF6 based on EDMX inside .Net core.
[Limitations for EF6 in .NetCore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYvml.png)

Here's the link to the blog.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-6-3-preview-with-net-core-support/

You have two options if you still want to use .Net Core 3.1, either convert your EDMX based EF6 to code based EF6. Another option is to convert your EF6 to EF Core.

I ended up converting our data project from EF6 to EFcore because we were only using EF6 for the EDMX model building. Plus, EFCore is way better than EF6 due to its performance and API libraries. It definitely is worth the migration.

Comment: Hey there! This is just a guess, but you appear to be affiliated with the blog you have posted.

Comment: No, I didn't post that blog, I got that blog from Microsoft's docs itself.